# How can I swap words that contain special punctuation in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have many strings similar to `` "Edit the file `my-file.conf`" `` and I want to change them to `` "Edit the `my-file.conf` file" ``. Note that the file names are in backticks and not single quotes (I couldn't see how to illustrate that in this editor). I've tried numerous alternatives but always seem to get hung up on the backticks. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean anything like this (I've edited your question)? Notice that ``bla `bli` blo`` can be generated by writing ``` ``bla `bli` blo`` ``` (fantastic, in the comments it doesn't work :/ ).

Comment: Is "I have many strings similar to" an important part of the problem? Is it an operation you need to perform "en masse" or is it an operation you need to perform often? Also, are the double quotes actually part of the text?

Comment: Maybe I can't see an important detail, but why don't you simply change the position of the previous word (in this case,  `file`) using macros?

Comment: This is a regularly occurring operation, not a one-time, en masse operation. No, the double quotes are not part of the string; they appear that way after Enlico edited my post. One string might be exactly as posted, another might be "Open the playbook `playbook.yml`" and another might be something different. wrt using macros, that might well be possible too, but I'm not an accomplished Vim user and haven't used macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been meaning to create some clean functions to do this (maybe someone else
will provide them), but for now I have the following (hacky) remaps in my
vimrc:

```
" use [w and ]w and [W and ]W to exchange a word/WORD under the cursor with
" the prev/next one
nnoremap ]w mx$ox<ESC>kJ`xdawhelphmx$"_daw`xh
nnoremap ]W mx$ox<ESC>kJ`xdaWElphmx$"_daw`xh
nnoremap [w mx$ox<ESC>kJ`xdawbPhmx$"_daw`xh
nnoremap [W mx$ox<ESC>kJ`xdaWBPhmx$"_daw`xh
```

#### Make them repeatable with tpope's [vim-repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat)

```
" apply the repeat plugin to any mapping
function! Repeat(mapname, map, command)
    execute 'nnoremap <silent> <Plug>'.a:mapname.' '.a:command.
                \' :call repeat#set("\<Plug>'.a:mapname.'")<CR>'
    execute 'nmap '.a:map.' <Plug>'.a:mapname
endfunction

" use [w and ]w and [W and ]W to exchange a word/WORD under the cursor with
" the prev/next one
call Repeat('WordForward', ']w', 'mx$ox<ESC>kJ`xdawhelphmx$"_daw`xh')
call Repeat('WORDForward', ']W', 'mx$ox<ESC>kJ`xdaWElphmx$"_daw`xh')
call Repeat('WordBackward', '[w', 'mx$ox<ESC>kJ`xdawbPhmx$"_daw`xh')
call Repeat('WORDBackward', '[W', 'mx$ox<ESC>kJ`xdaWBPhmx$"_daw`xh')
```

Comment: This also seems to fail when backticks are involved. I haven't done much key mapping in Vim, but this *does* work with plain text (similar to hdeep).

Comment: I don't know why but the uppercase versions appear to do nothing. afaik `hdeep` is a native Vim operation (perhaps like `dw` and `2dw` etc. Am I doing something wrong with my mapping? Possibly. Is the first remap of your first post correct or is it missing two chars off the end? Thanks

Comment: I removed the trailing`')` as mentioned and now `]W` does what I want, thanks. I also discovered that my two `Shift` keys work differently in this scenario. This works with left `Shift` but not right. No idea why. Thanks for all effort and help.

Comment: @DavidO'Brien Great I'm glad we got there in the end. The `Shift` key thing is strange, for me it works with either key - when you type a capital letter in insert mode using either key, do they both produce the expected result? I wonder if you capslock was on for one of your tests (and so when you pressed `right Shift` it was actually doing this `}w` rather than this `]W`)?

Comment: Yes the Shift keys work normally in all other scenarios that I'm aware of. I basically type all day and all keys get a workout. I know my Ctrl keys are different, but that's by design. I usually know when CapsLock is on because the lights on my kbd change :)

Comment: @DavidO'Brien hmmmm that's bizarre - there's nothing I can see in the maps that would have a differential effect on the shift keys... and 'it works on my system' :) One thing to try would be to put the maps into .vimrc all by themselves and see if the issue persists. Then you would know if they're somehow interacting with some other setting you have in your current vimrc.